# QGIS v2.18.9 layer visibility

Tags: qgis, layers, sql-view

When I add a new layer to a QGIS project it is often not visible in the viewing pane, although it is visible in the side Layers Panel.

I would like to make the layer visible and have tried to use the mouse to drag and drop the layer to the top of the layers panel.  This however crashes the programme.  The only work around I have found is to remove the basemap raster layer and then reinstall it.

I have attached a screenshot which shows the 'boundary' layer in the layers panel but not visible in the main viewing pane.

[image: ]]

Comment: It's not visible because it's underneath the raster layer. Either you use transparency on your raster or you move the boundary layer up one step

Comment: Also try to update you r QGIS to the latest version of 2.18.13. It may solve the crash issue.

Comment: Pleas do not UPCASE your title. It makes it harder to read and will generate downvotes.

Comment: did you check the Layer Order Panel?

Comment: Thank you all for suggestions.  I have tried moving layers using Layer Order Panel and simply clicking and dragging layers in Layers Panel - both crash my machine.  Raster layer transparency is a good tip though which will be useful. I will also update to 2.18.13.  Upcasing titles being hard to read is a new one on me - when I first used email 25 years ago, I was told to put the subject in caps as you would in a business letter. You live and learn!

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid to end at the bottom of the layer list, before doing the *drag & drop* of your new layer file, place yourself somewhere above any raster layer that might mask your new one.

In your case, you could be on top of the layer with points, so your *Boundary* will be added in the second place and it will not be masked by *nt75se*.